# Sub Called When Using Worksheet_Change Won't Run

Tags: excel, call, worksheet, vba

I'm trying to call a sub called ScaleAxes that sits in a module elsewhere. The ScaleAxes code is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ScaleAxes()
  Worksheets("Dashboard").ChartObjects("Measure Chart").Activate
  With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    .MaximumScale = Sheets("Lists and Data").Range("R7").Value
    .MinimumScale = Sheets("Lists and Data").Range("Q7").Value
    .MajorUnit = Sheets("Lists and Data").Range("S7").Value
  End With
  With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
    .MaximumScale = Sheets("Lists and Data").Range("R9").Value
    .MinimumScale = Sheets("Lists and Data").Range("Q9").Value
    .MajorUnit = Sheets("Lists and Data").Range("S9").Value
  End With
End Sub
```

The code I'm trying to call it in is here:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("H2:N2")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then
        Dim addIn As COMAddIn
        Dim automationObject As Object
        Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("PI DataLink")
            Set automationObject = addIn.Object
        Dim MyRange As Range
            Set MyRange = Range("J2")
            MyRange.Select
            automationObject.SelectRange
            automationObject.ResizeRange
            Application.CalculateFull
     End If
     If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then
        Call ScaleAxes
    End If
End Sub
```

ScaleAxes works on its own when I run it separately, and no error comes up when the code it's called in is run. The problem is that the code above seems to run properly, but the ScaleAxes code doesn't run. I've also tried pulling the code out of the ScaleAxes() sub and pasting it into the IF function that the working part of the code is in, but that didn't work either.

Any help you can provide helping me remedy this issue would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

Here's my code in its current state:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C2:G2")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then
        Dim addIn As COMAddIn
        Dim automationObject As Object
        Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("PI DataLink")
            Set automationObject = addIn.Object
        Dim MyRange As Range
            Set MyRange = Range("N2")
            MyRange.Select
            automationObject.SelectRange
            automationObject.ResizeRange
            Application.CalculateFull
    End If
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then
        Call ScaleAxes
    End If
End Sub
```

The same problem is occurring. The code above is in Sheet2(Dashboard) and the code being called is in Module2.

**EDIT 2:**

Just as an update. When I call the ScaleAxes sub using a Command Button it works. This is OK as a temporary resolution, but I'd like to have the sub called at the same time as the rest of the code if possible.

Comment: Change `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` to `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: @PortlandRunner I made the change you suggested but still got the same issue.

Comment: Quick check, is the Worksheet_SelectionChange code in the code behind the worksheet of interest?  Once I made the method change I could run your code just fine.

Comment: Do you mean do I have the second block of code in my original post in the "Dashboard" sheet? Then yes. I have that code there and the code I'm trying to call in a separate module. I modified the code slightly, I'll add that to my original post as an edit.

Comment: just to confirm, @nickelcap , you are checking for the intersection on `C2:G2` so it will definitely not run if you change any other cells, correct?

Comment: @Raugmor I think you may have hit on something. The idea is for the user to select an item from a drop down list that are in that cell range, and if any of those cells change the code runs.

Comment: @nickelcap so does it RUN when you change those intersect cells or it does NOT but you expect it too? Also, do you have the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` macro enabled on the same sheet by any chance?

Comment: Reason i am asking about selection change as you do have a selection change within the above code and it might trigger something else that wouldn't let the macro run further. You can also try to put a stop point on the intersect check and see if it even does go into the `Sub` and if it does, does it go into the `if` condition